# PHP Change Array Over and Over

Tags: php

I have any array

```
$num_list = array(42=>'0',44=>'0',46=>'0',48=>'0',50=>'0',52=>'0',54=>'0',56=>'0',58=>'0',60=>'0');
```

and I want to change specific values as I go through a loop

```
    while(list($pq, $oin) = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) {
        $num_list[$oin] = $pq;
    }
```

So I want to change like 58 to 403 rather then 0.

However I always end up getting just the last change and non of the earlier ones. So it always ends up being something like
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,403
rather then
14,19,0,24,603,249,0,0,0,403

How can I do this so it doesn't overwrite it?

Thanks

Comment: What are the values that `$pq` and `$oin` can have?

Comment: Sorry, let me explain a bit more.
$oin must be a value in the array (42,44,46,48,50,etcetc)
$pq can be any WHOLE number.

Comment: So, you wish to overwrite it only with values bigger than "0" or just one value (you select) at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you explicititly coded that each entry should be replaced with the values from the database (even with "0").
You could replace the values on non-zero-values only:

```
while(list($pq, $oin) = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) {
    if ($pq !== "0") $num_list[$oin] = $pq;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get you more clear, i thought your asking this only.  Check this

```
while(list($pq, $oin) = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) {
       if($oin==58) {
           $num_list[$oin] = $pq;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my simulated tests (although You are very scarce with information), Your code works well and produces the result that You want. Check the second query parameter, that You put into array - namely $pg, thats what You should get there 0,0,0,0,0...403 OR Other thing might be that Your $oin numbers are not present in $num_list keys. 
I tested Your code with mysqli driver though, but resource extraction fetch_row is the same.

Bear in mind one more thing - if Your query record number is bigger than $numlist array, and $oin numbers are not unique, Your $numlist may be easily overwritten by the folowing data, also $numlist may get a lot more additional unwanted elements.

Always try to provide the wider context of Your problem, there could be many ways to solve that and help would arrive sooner.